# If Gravitational potential energy increase with height then why it is 0 at infinity?

Tags: energy, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy, conventions

Due to MGH relation, if we increase height then potential energy increases. Then why it is zero at infinity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that two things are important here:

1) Potential energy is defined up to a constant. The absolute value of potential energy is not relevant, but the difference of potential energy between two points. Having this in mind it is possible to set a height for which the potential gravitational energy equals zero. Let's say that we pick that height to be $h_{0}$, then by redefining the gravitational energy as $E_{g}=mg(h-h_{0})$ we obtain the desired result. Clearly in $E=mgh$ the zero energy is at zero height.

2) I think that your question is related to two different models for the gravitational phenomena that are useful each on a different scale.

Let's consider a particle of mass $m$ in the gravitational field of the Earth (call $M$ the mass of the Earth). According to the Newton law of gravitation, the gravitational force between this two particles is attractive and of module $$F(r)=\frac{GMm}{r^{2}},$$where $r$ is the distance between the particle and the center of the Earth.  As we can see this force is not constant, and the gravitational potential -taking into account the point 1)- can be defined as $$E(r)=-\frac{GMm}{r}+C,$$ with $C$ a constant (this constant would be the potential energy at infinity, and it is customary to chose $C=0$).

Note that this potential energy is very different than $mgh$ (note that $h=r-R$ where $R$ is the radius of the Earth). This difference comes from the fact that $E=mgh$, comes from assuming that the gravitational force is constant. This approximation is valid only on the surface of the Earth, where the height doesn't vary much. Using this approximation for very large $h$ wouldn't make sense.

Physically, the gravitational force is not really constant, but decreasing with the square of the distance, which implies that bringing a particle from infinity would not take an infinite amount of energy, and hence we can choose the energy to be zero at infinty and still have a finite value at finite $r>0$. However, bringing a particle from infinity against a constant force would indeed take an infinite ammount of energy, and in this case, if we defined the potential energy to be "zero at infinity" we would have infinite values for the energy in nearby points.

Answer (score 1):

Because **potential energy can be less than zero.**

- You are right that potential energy increases with height.
- You are also right that potential energy can be defined to be zero at infinity.

These two facts are not in conflict. Because, maybe the potential energy at ground-level is **negative**. Then it can surely **increase with height** until it is **zero when infinitely far away**.

The reference, the zero-point, can be chosen arbitrarily because only the difference in potential energy matters. Choosing the zero-value to be at infinity is just an arbitrary (and sometimes convenient) choice. You can also choose it to be zero at ground-level in other scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Potential energy is defined by integrating Newton's second law. There is therefore an arbitrary constant in the definition of potential energy. You can therefore choose the point at which potential energy is zero. In some cases you might want to choose a height related to the problem in hand. For example you may choose ground level, or the height of an object in the initial condition. For problems involving gravitating bodies like the Sun, where you are using the inverse square law, it is generally most natural and convenient to chose the zero of potential energy at infinity.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible because the potential is negative and its increase diminishes with hight. The mgh law is just an approximation to the potential at the Earth's surface for height difference much smaller than $R_E$.